# How to write result in a file by using node.js and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I've built an application using node.js and express.js on top of elasticsearch. This is very simple application with a search box. When you search for a query, it prints result in JSON format. For eg, if I search for keyword "white", the output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHuWl.png

Now I want to store this result in a file(for eg output.json).This is my json file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = "output.json";
var express = require('express'); //To make use of Express' routing capabilities you need to initiate a new Express Router.
var router = express.Router(); //To make use of Express' routing capabilities you need to initiate a new Express Router. get, put, post, delete, all

var searchModule = require('../search_module/search.js');


//There are two ways of using the router methods. You can define one route (for example /home) and attach the methods to it, or you can create a new method for each route.
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) { //.get() - when you visit a website you make a GET request. You can get data from a URL in a GET request too.
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/search-results', function(req, res) {//.post() is a method used everywhere for posting data to a server / app. You'll want to use this for submitting forms.
  searchModule.search(req.body, function(data) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', results: data });
  });
});



fs.writeFile(path,data,function(err){
     if(err) console.error(err);
})

module.exports = router;
```

When I tried using writeFile method of node.js, I am getting an Reference error showing that "data" is not defined. My error looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwXfW.png

I am not able to figure out this error. Is there any other way to write the output to a file by using node.js and express?

Edit: I edited my javascript

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = "output.json";
var express = require('express'); //To make use of Express' routing capabilities you need to initiate a new Express Router.
var router = express.Router(); //To make use of Express' routing capabilities you need to initiate a new Express Router. get, put, post, delete, all

var searchModule = require('../search_module/search.js');


//There are two ways of using the router methods. You can define one route (for example /home) and attach the methods to it, or you can create a new method for each route.
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) { //.get() - when you visit a website you make a GET request. You can get data from a URL in a GET request too.
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/search-results', function(req, res) {//.post() is a method used everywhere for posting data to a server / app. You'll want to use this for submitting forms.
  searchModule.search(req.body, function(data) {
    fs.writeFile(path,data,function(err){
       if(err) console.error(err);
    })
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', results: data });
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

But when I ran this javascript, I got this output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfBq0.png

I am not getting the JSON output. My output should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHuWl.png

I am also using an ejs file with my javascript for the frontend(index.ejs) which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <form action='/search-results' method='post'>
      <input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="your search term here">
      <button type="submit"> SEARCH </button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <% if(locals.results) { %>
      <pre>
           <%= JSON.stringify(results,null,2) %>
        </pre>
        <% results.forEach( function( result ) }) %>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do I need to get output from this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable is not defined at this point.
You can move your `fs.writeFile` function in the `searchModule.search` call like this:

```
searchModule.search(req.body, function(data) {
    fs.writeFile(path,data,function(err){
       if(err) console.error(err);
    })
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', results: data });
});
```

or declare your variable before and set it in the `searchModule.search` call, to be disponible after in the scope to write your file:

```
var fileData;

searchModule.search(req.body, function(data) {
    fileData = data;
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', results: data });
});

fs.writeFile(path,fileData,function(err){
   if(err) console.error(err);
})
```

Comment: Please check my updated post. I tried to use your 1st solution, but now my  "output.json" looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/rfBq0.png

Comment: This is already much better. Depends on your data, but maybe you have to use something like `JSON.stringify(data)` to convert your data into plain JSON.

Comment: I am also using an ejs file for the frontend to display results. I have updated my post to include that file. Do I need to get my result from this ejs file because I have used JSON.stringify here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this block:

```
fs.writeFile(path,data,function(err){
     if(err) console.error(err);
})
```

You've declared `path` at the top of your code, but `data` appears to be undefined in this context.

Comment: Yes. I have declared a path(output.json) where I want to store my output. As you can see from my post method, I want to use that data to append to my file "output.json".

Comment: As @TGrif points out, you have two ways to go with this. Because `data` is valid inside your post method, you can 1. call `writeFile` from that spot in the post method or 2. declare a new variable at the top of your file which stores the `data` coming in your post method.

Comment: You may need to do: `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I am also using an ejs file for the frontend to display results. I have updated my post to include that file. Do I need to get my result from this ejs file because I have used JSON.stringify here.

Comment: Try leaving the sever-side `data` alone, and from the .ejs file, try `<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>`